# 'next' button not showing all hidden sibling divs; it stops at the second and does not advance to last div. [jquery, js, html5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have designed an i-phone-like screen on a web browser where I am testing this application I am in the process of building. There will be two video windows, the second of which is hidden.(SEE IMAGE ATTACHED)

[image: SCREENSHOT OF APPLICATION WINDOW]

The user views the main channel as the page loads and can access the second window if she so chooses through a button. The videos playing on the main channel are those related to this channel only, and the second window gives access to the other channels, and shows the user what's playing.

Everything works fine, *except that I am using the 'next' button on the second video window and not advancing to the third video on the list. I am not sure why it's not showing.* The 'prev' button shows the third video perfectly. The code I am using is basically the same I used on the top video section, where everything worked.

---

Below is the section of the code that I am using for prev and next on the three videos of this specific section that is NOT working.

**html code for 3 videos (w some inline js)**

```
<div id="bottomVid">
<div class="videoContainerTwo channelPolitics">

<div class="topHorizontalButtonRow"><a href="#" class="buttonLeftTriangleBlue channelPolitics" id="prevButtonBottom"></a>
 <a href="#" class="buttonRightTriangleBlue channelPolitics" id="nextButtonBottom"></a>
</div>

 <video loop onclick="this.paused? this.play() : this.pause()" >
<source src="videos/Politics_Refugee_Sign.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></div>


<div class="videoContainerTwo channelKillingTheEyelinerGame hiddenElement">
  <div class="topHorizontalButtonRow">
          <a href="#" class="buttonLeftTriangleBlue channelKillingTheEyelinerGame" id="prevButtonBottom"></a>
        <a href="#" class="buttonRightTriangleBlue channelPolitics" id="nextButtonTop"></a>
          </div>

<video loop onclick="this.paused? this.play() : this.pause()" >
<source src="videos/killing the eyeliner game_horiz mob sz.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></div>

<div class="videoContainerTwo channelParisIsBurning hiddenElement">
  <div class="topHorizontalButtonRow">
          <a href="#" class="buttonLeftTriangleBlue channelParisIsBurning" id="prevButtonBottom"></a>
        <a href="#" class="buttonRightTriangleBlue channelParisIsBurning" id="nextButtonTop"></a>
          </div>


<video loop onclick="this.paused? this.play() : this.pause()" >
<source src="videos/ParisisBurning_370x660_Get_Into_The_Suits_Vert.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></div>
</div>
```

**THE ISSUE:** JS code for 'next' navigation [this only goes up to the second video and stops there]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bottomVid.videoContainerTwo").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#nextButtonBottom.buttonRightTriangleBlue").click(function(){
        if ($(".videoContainerTwo:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").hide();
            $(".videoContainerTwo:first").show();
        }
        return false;

    });
```

**THE 'PREV' NAVIGATION WORKS AND THE CODE IS ALMOST THE SAME:** JS code for "prev" navigation [this works perfectly, I see all 3 videos and it loops through the 3 videos]

```
  $("#prevButtonBottom.buttonLeftTriangleBlue").click(function(){
      if ($(".videoContainerTwo:visible").prev().length != 0)
          $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
      else {
          $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").hide();
          $(".videoContainerTwo:last").show();
      }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you found the problem. However, I think I found something else:

Shouldn't

```
$("#nextButtonBottom.buttonRightTriangleBlue").click(function(){
    if ($(".videoContainerTwo:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").hide();
        $(".videoContainerTwo:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Be

```
$("#nextButtonBottom.buttonRightTriangleBlue").click(function(){
    if ($(".videoContainerTwo:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".videoContainerTwo:visible").hide();
        $(".videoContainerTwo:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Note I changed `last` to `first` on line 6. Since you're wrapping around, after item 3 is shown and someone clicks NEXT, it will go back to item 1, correct? So it should show the FIRST, not the LAST. Amirite?

Comment: Yes, actually I had corrected that on my code and did not update the answer. Last night in desperation I copied the code from the one that was working ('prev') to see if that would work. That is why the "last" is still there:) Thank you! Updated the code here too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stepped through in Debugging to see how each element is affected when clicking those buttons? Also, making sure that the referenced IDs and Classes are correct in the jQuery.

Comment: Thank you!!! Debugging didn't yield much, I double-checked the IDs on the problematic section yet again and found the culprit. I had the wrong ID on the 'next' button for the bottom video that was not showing.

Comment: I figured the answer was something simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: the ID on the item that was not showing up was not correct (not matching the jquery code). @LegendaryJLD pointed me on the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: I also made something a little bit more complicated than necessary, there are multiple instances of jquery next and prev buttons, one for each "channel". (As opposed to one for all the videos on the entire bottom section). Because I had trouble with seeing only the videos for a specific channel on a previous edit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023814/alternating-multiple-video-lists-in-html5-stored-as-javascript-arrays), I made it sort of truncated. The bottom videos will then lead the user to change the channel so I felt I had to keep the classes consistent and clear.